# What if we take scalar product of angular velocity and position vector?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, vectors, angular-velocity

Since vector cross product of angular velocity and position vector gives velocity vector, what if we take scalar product of angular velocity and position vector? We can take vector cross product of force and distance it gives torque. And if we take scalar product of force and position vector it gives work.

Comment: OP is asking whether there is any meaning to the scalar product of angular velocity and the position vector.

Comment: If you multiply the angular velocity times the radius (for a particle moving in a circle), you get the magnitude of the tangential velocity.

Comment: Position vector is a vector going from the axis of rotation to the point (this is the definition that we use when we talk about things like  $ \vec r \times \vec F$ this in rotational Mechanics)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What if we take scalar product of angular velocity and position vector?

You'll get a value if you compute this as this is a valid mathematical operation. The question then is whether this value has a useful meaning in physics. The answer is, not that much.

This inner product is sometimes useful in that it yields an expression for the angle between the angular velocity vector and the position vector:
$$\cos \theta = \frac{\vec{\omega}\cdot\vec{r}}{||\vec{\omega}||\cdot||\vec{r}||}$$
In the case of the Earth, this angle is closely related to geocentric latitude. The angle calculated above is the colatitude (co-geocentric latitude), which is related to geocentric latitude via $\theta + \phi = \frac\pi2$, and thus
$$\sin \phi = \frac{\vec{\omega}\cdot\vec{r}}{||\vec{\omega}||\cdot||\vec{r}||}$$
The inner product readily yields the projection of the position vector onto the angular velocity vector:
$$ \vec r_{||} = \frac{\vec\omega \cdot \vec r}{\vec\omega \cdot \vec\omega}\vec\omega = \frac{\vec\omega \cdot \vec r}{\omega^2}\vec\omega$$
Subtracting this from the position vector yields the component of the position vector that is orthogonal to the angular velocity vector:
$$\vec r_{\perp} \equiv \vec r - \vec r_{||} = \vec r - \frac{\vec\omega \cdot \vec r}{\omega^2}\vec\omega$$
An alternative expression for the above using the vector triple product is
$$\vec r_{\perp} = \frac{\vec\omega\times(\vec r \times \vec\omega)}{\omega^2}$$
While the above calculations are occasionally useful, none is especially useful, at least not compared to how useful both the vector and scalar products of force and displacement are.